# How to make a cron job run on the eighths of every hour

Tags: cron

I have a cron job that I want to run at 8 minutes past the hour, at 18 minutes past the hour, at 28 minutes past the hour, and so on. I tried this but got an "invalid minute" error.

```
8/10 * * * * /home/snrub/file.php
```

Can this be done?

Comment: From the cron tag: Questions about configuring cron for systems or administration are OFF TOPIC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sure can!

```
08,18,28,38,48,58 * * * * /home/snrub/file.php
```